# dhcp server on Ubuntu 23.04 failed

Tags: server, syslinux

When I check for the status of my DHCP server with "sudo systemctl status isc-dhcp-server", the system shows server failed.

Comment: Did you disable the default DHCP server? Read `man systemd-dnsmasq`. Your Question has very little information.Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.